# What are other Update repositories for?

Tags: opensuse, flatpak

The two standard update repositories included with an openSuse installation are:

```
repo-update               | Main Update Repository                              | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.2/oss
repo-update-non-oss       | Update Repository (Non-Oss)                         | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.2/non-oss
```

I wanted to install `flatpak` and it wasn't included in any of the standard OpenSuse repositories, yet is included in this "standard" one:

```
https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:Leap:15.2:Update/standard/openSUSE:Leap:15.2:Update.repo
```

I'm wondering how I am to easily distinguish between the two repositories. Why is there another update repository containing different packages that is called "standard"?

Edit:
Attempting to refresh the repository, the following error occurred:

```
Retrieving repository 'Online updates for openSUSE Leap:15.2 (standard)' m[error]
Repository 'Online updates for openSUSE Leap:15.2 (standard)' is invalid.
[openSUSE_Leap_15.2_Update|http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.2/oss/] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
History:
 - File './repodata/52abefe790b7ec6458fe16d156d257fd9c71239c804b1276d350c7e4ef2bf33a-primary.xml.gz' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.2/oss/'
 - Can't provide ./repodata/52abefe790b7ec6458fe16d156d257fd9c71239c804b1276d350c7e4ef2bf33a-primary.xml.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to install flatpak and it wasn't included in any of the standard OpenSuse repositories

This is weird as confirmed on Flatpak website (https://flatpak.org/setup/openSUSE/) and openSUSE website (https://software.opensuse.org/package/flatpak).

Flatpak is part of the openSUSE Leap 15.2 official update repository, that is supposed to be activated by default.

What version of openSUSE do you actually use ? Leap 15.2 ? Maybe you removed this repository in the past, or you inactivated it ?

> I'm wondering how I am to easily distinguish between the two repositories.

You can check Yast software repositories or `zypper repos --details`to quickly see what repositories you have and which ones are activated.

For a given package, Yast or `zypper info flatpak` (or any other package name) will tell you which repository it comes from.

> Why is there another update repository containing different packages that is called "standard"?

I couldn't tell "why" :-) but per openSUSE documentation (https://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories) this update repository is indeed what I would expect for Leap 15.2, beside OSS and Non-OSS. And it is intended to be a "Repository of official security and bugfix updates for OSS packages. "

What I would do :

- Check in Yast or `zypper repos --details` that the update repository is present and enabled. For Leap 15.2, the URI field should be `http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.2/oss/`. Enable (`sudo zypper modifyrepo --enable alias-of-the-repo`) or add it if needed.
- Remove the repo you've manually added if you added one, because it probably duplicates with the one initially provided.
- Refesh all your repos with `sudo zypper refresh`
- Try to install flatpak from your repository with Yast or `sudo zypper install flatpak`
- If it doesn't work, update your post here with the error message that you obtain.
- Once flatpak is installed, don't forget to provide it with some flatpak repositories too, for example `flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo` to add Flathub.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered the source of my error. It's rather embarrassing, so please excuse me for not describing the exact nature of it.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if I could help ! :-)